# Finding the preferred application for a given file extension via unix shell commands

Tags: unix, command-line, file-extension, user-preferences

this may not be *strictly* about programming, but if I find no ready-made solution it may become a programming task:  **On UNIX, what is a command-line method for determining the user-preferred application for a given filetype?**

My ideal solution here would be a command that stopped me having to do the following:

```
okular foo.pdf
```

And allowed me to do something like this, working with my set preferred applications:

```
launch foo.pdf
```

I found no answer by searching, and a DIY approach wouldn't work as, while I've been using Linux for a while, I have no clue of the internals that manage my preferred applications.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On unix *per se* that would be the one the user used to open it, because there is no OS level notion of a preferred application.

However the major X desktop environment all define such a notion, and then you have to use their facilities:

- [`gnome-open`](http://embraceubuntu.com/2006/12/16/gnome-open-open-anything-from-the-command-line/) in GNOME (duh)
- `exo-open` in XFCE [see the comments in the gnome link]
- `xdg-open` may work in many environments (reputedly works in KDE) [see the comments in the gnome link]
- just plain `kfmclient exec` (or `kfmclient4 exec`) in KDE (I haven't been able to find a reference to `kde-open` as [Rob H suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1949531/finding-the-preferred-application-for-a-given-file-extension-via-unix-shell-comma/1949732#1949732), and don't have a KDE system at hand to try it)

Now Mac OS X provides the `open` command which works like clicking the file in the finder (which is to say, it asks the OS...)

---

Several corrections thanks to [ephemient](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20713/ephemient) in the comments. I won't discuss `mailcap`, because I never understood it and had forgotten it existed...

Comment: `xdg-open` isn't from xdm, it's from http://portland.freedesktop.org/ and designed to be desktop-agonistic; the KDE example is inaccurate, it's `kfmclient exec` (or `kfmclient4 exec` if you distribution renames binaries); you left out mention of the traditional `mailcap` mechanism.

Comment: xdg-open seems to be exactly what I'm looking for here.  Lovely.

Answer (score 1):

The answer differs depending on the desktop environment your using. Since you mentioned Okular, I'm going to assume you're using KDE. So try:

```
kde-open <file>
```

For GNOME, there is the equivalent:

```
gnome-open <file>
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer this myself, I've defined a simple (bash) function that works in the way I expect:

```
function show { 
    xdg-open $1 &> NUL
    }
```

xdg-open was almost exactly what I wanted, but it lets ugly program warnings slip through into the shell, which the above seems to fix.

Thanks all.

Comment: piping to `NUL` creates a file called `NUL`. I think you want `/dev/null`, which is a true 'black hole'.